# Bring up Dialogs directly?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have the following Code for a Button, which i want to built up a Socket Connection and then try to send data over the Network. When i have no Server for the Socket it takes a few seconds before the App recognizes and i get an error. In this time the App do nothing (as u could expect) to have a simple Notification for the User to show him the App is not broken, i want to bring up a little ProgressBar.

```
private void sendButtonListener(Button sendButton, final String server,
        final int port) {
    sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            refreshInput();

            showDialog(DIALOG_CONNECTING);
            //Getting the SocketConnection and try to send the Data
            attempToSendXML(builder, profilename);
            dismissDialog(DIALOG_CONNECTING);
        }
    });
}
```

My Problem is that it seems that the `showDialog()` Method is brings up the ProgressBar after the `onClick(View v)` Method is finished. So for my example it shows just nothing (it just hangs until the the `attempToSendXML()` method is finished), because i close the Dialog after i tried to send the Data.

I hope u guys get my Point and can help me. I've been looking around for 2 hours now and really don't get it ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not block the UI thread with a long operation like `attempToSendXML()`.

Instead you should use an AsyncTask. The AsyncTask should be the solution to your problem as well.

See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html).

The AsyncTask has an `onPreExecute()`-method where you show up your dialog. `attempToSendXML()` will then be executed in the method `doInBackground` and the dialog is closed in the method `onPostExecute` of the AsyncTask. By doing it this way you do not block the UI-Thread (and get no ANR exception) and the progress dialog shows a long as the operation is working in the background.